# how to get formatted date string

Tags: angular, flatpickr

my flatpickrOptions looks like :

```
    public exampleOptions: FlatpickrOptions = {
           enableTime: true,
           dateFormat: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        };
```

html code : `<ng2-flatpickr [config]="exampleOptions" [(ngModel)]="dateTime"></ng2-flatpickr>`

but I get object instead of a string. something like : `[Wed Oct 04 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)]`

How can I get formatted date string instead of in my typescript method?

Answer (score 5):

I found `moment` more reliable than `date pipes`

To include moment just import it in the component

```
// Moment
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';
```

And you can use it in your like this.

```
var myVar = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You can check official website for more options
[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I want to get a formatted date in my typescript, not html.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to display a formatted date inside your HTML you can use the `date` pipe

`{{ time.arrivee | date:'H:mm:ss' }}`

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this :

First, I get `moment(this.dateTime[0])`,

so output was: `Wed Oct 04 2017 11:24:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)`.

Then I want to get formatted DateTime string what I've done with moment: `moment(this.dateTime[0]).format('DD.MM.YYYY H:mm')`,

so output was: `04.10.2017 11:24` as I was expected.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer gave an idea. You can even simplify your answer by doing `moment(this.dateTime[0]).format('DD.MM.YYYY H:mm')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular pipes to get the required format as follows

{{element.invoiceDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy'}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way for `ng2-flatpickr`

```
  public Options = {
    altInput: true,
    mode: 'single',
    altInputClass: 'form-control flat-picker flatpickr-input invoice-edit-input',

    altFormat: 'Y-n-j',

    // ---- focused area (Here you can format as you can) ----
    onChange: (selectedDates: any) => {
      this.pickers.first.writeValue(new Date(selectedDates).toISOString().slice(0, 10));
    }
    // ---- focused area ----
  };
```